# Could not download gradle.jar (io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.0)

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I am creating an app in which i am using **Fabric**.Yesterday it was working fine but then today it gives the following error and gradle build is failing with the following error

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.>
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.>
 Could not download gradle.jar (io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.0)> 
 Could not get resource 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.22.0/gradle-1.22.0.jar'.> Connection reset
```

I have no idea how to resolve this error.Any help would be appricated

Comment: Can you access address `https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.22.0/gradle-1.22.0.jar` in your browser?

Comment: Yes but there is an error message in this link

Comment: So there is definitely problem with your internet connection because that link works for me (dialog for downloading file is shown). Try to tweak your connection to get this link working. You can try disabling firewall, antivirus, connect from elsewhere, etc..

Comment: By turning off firewall off it worked.but i don't understand why it happened.Turning off firewall is not recommended,isn't it?

Comment: Turning firewall off for short period of time should be almost no risk, especially with badly configured firewall that limits you in common work. But it is only my opinion. :-)  I am glad it is working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like temporary issues with `maven.fabric.io`. Had similar problems today, direct URL download was working, but Gradle download was very slow and finally got a connection reset. 15 minutes later everything was working fine.

Comment: I am getting a lot of connection resets as well today.